# Order ActiveRecord results alphabetically

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sql-order-by, rails-activerecord

I have an controller method like this:

```
def index
  @categories = Category.all
end
```

How do I order `@categories` names alphabetically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can `order`:

```
@categories = Category.order(:name)
```

Answer (score 2):

In you Categories Controller:

```
 class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

     def index
         @categories = Category.order(:name)
     end
  end
```

This will by default order the `:name` column in by alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

```
#default ascending

  class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @categories = Category.order(:name)
    end
  end

#explicit ascending if you were chaining a scope that has some other default order

  class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @categories = Category.tags.order(name: :asc)
    end
  end

#decending

 class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

   def index
     @categories = Category.tags.order(name: :desc)
   end
 end
```